# SQL: Conditional Select within Conditional Select

Tags: sql, select

Please bear with me on this, this is quite difficult to explain and I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology.

I need to do a rather complicated select. It is effectively a select statement which conditionally decides what field to use to filter the select. If a certain date field is not null, I need to check that the value in that field is within a certain range. Otherwise if that date field is null I need to check another field, int field, on the same table is within a certain range:

Pseudocode:

```
If [Date] is not null
    Get sum (table.value) for rows Date >= dateValue and Date < dateValue
Else
    Get sum (table.value) for rows Int >= intValue and Int < intValue
```

My current attempt:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Date IS NOT NULL THEN 
(SUM(CASE WHEN (a.Date >= cal.Date) THEN ABS(a.Value) ELSE 0 END)) 
ELSE 
(SUM(CASE WHEN (b.Days >= 0) THEN ABS(a.Value) ELSE 0 END) 
END AS 'A'
```

Any ideas? Ask if you need more information. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup. Cheers. I had an or statement originally but the Integer field would be dragged even if the date field contained data but simply did not fall within the range. Didn't think of add a null check in there! Ouch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to have 2 separate queries UNIONed together, but only one clause will produce a value. This avoids having OR statements.

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Date >= dateValue and Table.Date < dateValue  --NULL Date = false always
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Int >= intValue and Table.Int < intValue
    AND --ignore this clause if date is NOT NULL
    MyTable.Date IS NULL
```

Edit, with OR:

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM MyTable
WHERE
     (
      MyTable.Date IS NOT NULL AND 
      MyTable.Date >= dateValue and Table.Date < dateValue
      )
      OR --actually mutually exclusive
     (
      MyTable.Date IS NULL AND 
      MyTable.Int >= intValue and Table.Int < intValue 
      )
```

Comment: This will return two separate sums, not a single sum of the two possible conditions.  It's hard to tell what the original poster is asking about, but it sounds like the goal is just a single value.

Comment: @Sam: why will it? Clause 1 gives no rows is DATE is NULL, so clause 2 applies. And clause 2 tests for DATE is NULL... if NOT NULL clause 1 will give rows (if range filters are true of course). If you want, you can add DATE IS NOT NULL to the 1st clause

Comment: Yes, Sorry it is hard to explain. I effectively have rows of results but for reasons not worth going into here the row is identified as being within a certain range either with a date field, or an integer field, not both. The date field takes priority but if it's null I use the integer field but once selected I get the same value irrespective of how it was selected. Phew.

Comment: Yes. That sounds right! I'll test tomorrow when I have access to the database again! Thanks for the time so far though :)

Answer (score 1):

This works and isn't all that far off from the pseudocode, as long as I'm interpreting what you want to do correctly.

```
SELECT  SUM(Value)
FROM    T
WHERE
        CASE WHEN DateValue IS NOT NULL 
                THEN DateValue BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
                ELSE IntValue BETWEEN FromInt AND ToInt
                END
```